# Is it possible to get a (n-1)-argument function out of a n-argument function by setting one argument to a fixed value?

Tags: c++, partial-application

I was wondering if in C++ it was possible to get a function taking (n-1) arguments out of a function taking n arguments by setting the value for the nth argument to some value (to be determined at runtime)?

E.g. I would like to do something like the following:

```
float foo(float a, float b, float c){
  // do some stuff
}

float bar(float x, float y, float f(float q, float r)){
  return f(x,y);
}

int main(){
  double (*function)(float, float);
  float some_value;
  // somehow determine some_value, e.g. read from stdin.
  // Now I would like to set function something along the lines of:
  function = foo( . , . , some_value)
  return bar(123, 456, function);
}
```

Conceptually, `foo` is a family of functions indexed by `c`, i.e. a family of functions `foo_c (float a, float b)` (read "foo_c" as "foo subscript c" here), and I want to pass `foo_c` respectively a pointer to it as an argument to `bar`.

Is this possible at all in C++?
To the best of my knowledge, this isn't possible with function pointers as above. Is there any other way of doing something like this?

I briefly considered making `foo` a function template, but this won't work as I want to set it's third argument at runtime.

The obvious solution is of course to amend `bar` so as to take type `float f(float q, float r, float t)` as its third argument, but this would make the code a lot less reusable (and seems less elegant). I will want to pass other functions to `bar` as well, some of which will only take two arguments, more than three, or arguments of different types, which I somehow need to set to a fixed value before passing them to `bar`.

I haven't quite been able to figure out if I could make `bar` a template function in this case, along the lines of `template <typename T, typename S> float bar(float x, float y, T f(float a, float b, S param), S parameters)`, and then call it using something like `bar <double *(float, float, float), float> (123, 456, function, parameters)`. Would anything along these lines work at all?

Comment: For your Google-fu: this is called *partial application* and is supported natively by most modern programming languages, in particular those claiming to facilitate functional programming.

Comment: Partial application via `std::bind`.

Comment: Btw, the `f` parameter to `bar` is a function returning `float`, but you've defined your function pointer `function` to return `double`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do it with function pointers, however, it can be done with function objects.  I recommend you look at [Boost.Bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/bind/bind.html) if you're using C++03.  If you're using C++11, `std::bind` is part of the standard and works the same way.  C++11 also introduces built-in lambdas which do what you're attempting.

For storing the result of bind or a lambda, you can use [Boost.Function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/function.html) in C++03 or `std::function` in C++11.

This example is how you would do it in C++03.

```
float foo(float a, float b, float c){
  // do some stuff
}

float bar(float x, float y, boost::function<float(float,float)> f){
   return f(x,y);
}

int main(){
  boost::function<float(float,float)> func;
  float some_value;
  // somehow determine some_value, e.g. read from stdin.
  // Now I would like to set function something along the lines of:
  func= boost::bind(foo, _1, _2, some_value);
  return bar(123, 456, func);
}
```

In C++11, you could use the standardized versions of bind and function, or you could use the lambda feature:

```
float foo(float a, float b, float c){
  // do some stuff
}

float bar(float x, float y, std::function<float(float,float)> f){
   return f(x,y);
}

int main(){
  std::function<float(float,float)> func;
  float some_value;
  // somehow determine some_value, e.g. read from stdin.
  // Now I would like to set function something along the lines of:
  func= [some_value](float x, float y) { return foo(x,y,some_value); };
  return bar(123, 456, func);
}
```

Comment: ah, lambda expressions - very nifty! Many thanks for the help!
As a side note, it seems the same thing can be done on the Mac using C Blocks - it would then be `float (^func)(float, float) = ^(float x, float y){return foo(x,y,some_value);};`

Answer (score 4):

You can't do it with function pointers like that, but you can do it with function-like objects. C++11 gives you `std::bind` and `std::function` (and also lambdas, but I don't know enough about them to give an example); in C++03, `boost::bind` and `boost::function` are very similar.

```
float foo(float a, float b, float c){
  // do some stuff
}

float bar(float x, float y, function<float(float, float)> f){
  return f(x,y);
}

int main(){
  float some_value;
  // somehow determine some_value, e.g. read from stdin.

  return bar(123, 456, bind(foo,_1,_2,some_value));
}
```